# How to avoid files with permissions ???????? when building docker container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, file-permissions

In my dockerfile I added COPY to copy some files that I need to be available in the container. However when I ran the container, the permissions of the files are messed up.

```
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sleep_loop.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ojdbc6.jar
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? basefiles.csv
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? measure.csv
```

What I need to add in my `Dockerfile` in order to avoid this issue.

Here is my `COPY` command.

```
FROM xxxxx

USER root

COPY sleep_loop.sh   /home/mydir/
COPY ojdbc6.jar /home/mydir/
COPY basefiles.csv  /home/mydir/
COPY measure.csv  //home/mydir/

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel krb5-workstation krb5-devel wget gcc jce mysql-devel rsync git-all openssh-client && \
yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you run the image with a different user than root? [it looks](https://serverfault.com/questions/959354/file-permissions-have-question-marks-how-did-this-happen-how-to-scan-for-them) like you don't have execute permission in the folder /home/mydir

Comment: I ran using the same user root. I tried deleting the files after copying inside the same dockerfile and it gives me permission denied

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  (Are there any volume mounts?  Is the Dockerfile missing its `CMD`?)

Comment: The CMD is "CMD /home/mydir/sleep_loop.sh". I will try to add --volume when running the container

Comment: Tried adding volume, result is same some files are still having ???????? permission

Answer (score 0):

Your directory `/home/mydir` doesn't have execute permission.
Attach to the container and check it with `ls -ld /home/mydir`

```
FROM xxxxx

USER root

# make sure the directory exists and give it execute permission since they are apparently missing
RUN mkdir -p && chmod +x /home/mydir

# optionally merge the COPY statement to reduce the layers
COPY sleep_loop.sh ojdbc6.jar basefiles.csv measure.csv /home/mydir/

[..]
```